# POSTGRESQL: cron job 1 connection failed

Tags: postgresql, cron

Create a cron job to run a stored procedure with the configuration files:

/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_cron'    # (change requires restart)
cron.database_name='navstar_ankay'
```

/etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf

```
host    all             all             localhost               trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

restart postgresql

```
 sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

record the operation to be executed and the execution interval:

```
select cron.schedule('*1/ * * * *','CALL PROCESS_GPS();','localhost','5432','navstar_ankay','admin')
```

when I see the execution status I get an error message:

```
2021-07-03 16:23:00.000 UTC [163769] LOG:  cron job 1 starting: CALL PROCESS_GPS();
2021-07-03 16:23:00.013 UTC [163769] LOG:  cron job 1 connection failed
```

I break my head with this mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you also executed `CREATE EXTENSION pg_cron;` otherwise the `cron.schedule()` call would have failed.

Not sure why you have also allowed `0.0.0.0/0` in pg_hba.conf that means anywhere on earth (assuming IPv4 is not used outside of earth) ;)

When calling the `cron.schedule()`, which should be executed on the ${cron.database_name} database, you only need the schedule and the command (optionally you can add a job_name as firsst parameter). You don't need to give any connection parameters.

I did:

postgresql.conf:

```
shared_preload_libraries='pg_cron'
cron.database_name='navstar_ankay'
```

pg_hba.conf:

```
host    all         all          127.0.0.1/32           trust
```

at psql, connected to database navstar_ankay:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_cron;
CREATE PROCEDURE log_myproc() AS
$$
    begin
        raise log 'Procedimiento ejecutado a las: %', clock_timestamp();
    end;
$$ language plpgsql;

select cron.schedule('*1/ * * * *','CALL log_myproc()');
```

Comment: I tried to apply your solution but which one I assign like this:

host all all 127.0.0.1 trust

vote me an error of not being able to start

He asks me to put like this:
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust

by the way my database is:
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_cron'
cron.database_name = 'navstar_ankay'

Comment: yes, you're right it's `127.0.0.1/32` that line I did not copy&paste but rewrite it...
you can use the database you want, i used `postgres` but i could have used any other. the procedure should be in your `navstar_ankay` database of course. I'm editing my answer with that.

Comment: - did you restart postgresql after changing postgresql.conf?

- did you reloaded or restarted postgresql after changing pg_hba.conf?

- did you executed the `CREATE EXTENSION pg_cron` command on the same database that is mentioned in the `cron.database_name` parameter?

Comment: if I did everything indicated, as you can see in my code the cron.database_name with the assigned name

Comment: well, your description on the question cannot be entirely correct because the `cron.schedule()` function does not accept 6 parameters. If I try to execute it as you put it it gives me an error. That's why I ask to confirm. Can you please try my example as I showed? using the postgres database? after that works for you, we can continue from that.

Comment: I understand, the truth is that cron handles everything in a table and there I can do update and there are several ways to create one by making an insert and I can be sure that the job is inserted correctly

Comment: is this solved already? I bump into an exact same problem